# How to broadcast a specific QString on a QListView

Tags: qt, c++11, qt5, qstring, qlistview

**The problem:** I am trying to broadcast a specific `QString` on a `QListView` as shown below.
So in case I have specific measurments, I see them and they are published in the `QListView`, but if there are no measurements, I would like to broadcast a specific string " No Broadcasted data "

**Currently happening:**

[image: error]

**The Expected Result in case no measures are passed:**

[image: correct]

Below a snippet of the code I am using for the specific problem:

**qnode.hpp**

```
class QNode : public QThread {
Q_OBJECT

public:
    QNode(int argc, char** argv, const std::string &name );
    virtual ~QNode();

    QStringListModel* getMinDistanceModelQuad3() { return &minDistanceModelQuad3; }

protected:
    QStringListModel minDistanceModelQuad3;

};

#endif /* NODE_HPP_ */
```

**listener.h**

```
class Listener : public QNode {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Listener(int argc, char** argv);
    ~Listener();

private:
    void minimumDistanceQuad3Callback(const lidar_boat_detection::min_distance::ConstPtr& msg);
    ros::Subscriber min_distance_quad3_sub;
    QString distanceBroadcasted = "";
};
```

**listener.cpp**  <-- Where the messages are either published or no data is broadcasted

```
Listener::Listener(int argc, char** argv ) :
    QNode(argc,argv,"qlistener")
    {}

Listener::~Listener() {}

void Listener::ros_comms_init() {
    ros::NodeHandle n;

    // SUBSCRIBERS for distance calculation
    min_distance_quad3_sub = n.subscribe("min_distance_quad3", 10, &Listener::minimumDistanceQuad3Callback, this);
}

void Listener::minimumDistanceQuad3Callback(const lidar_boat_detection::min_distance::ConstPtr& msg)
{
  if(distanceBroadcasted.isEmpty()) {
    std::stringstream logging_msg;
    logging_msg << "[ INFO]"
        << " No Broadcasted data ";
    QVariant new_row(QString(logging_msg.str().c_str()));
    minDistanceModelQuad3.setData(minDistanceModelQuad3.index(0),new_row);
  } else {
    ROS_INFO("Minimum Distance Quad 3: [%f]", msg->distance);
    minDistanceModelQuad3.insertRows(0,1);
    std::stringstream logging_msg;
    logging_msg << "[ INFO]"
        << " Minimum Distance Quad 3: " << msg->distance;
    QVariant new_row(QString(logging_msg.str().c_str()));
    minDistanceModelQuad3.setData(minDistanceModelQuad3.index(0),new_row);
  }
}
```

I have been researching this problem for a while and I am not sure if this not proper behavior is due to a non-correct use of the `QVariant` property. 
Also I think I am correctly adding the correct message but despite that, it seems that the `QListView` receives measurements instead of "No Data Broadcasted " string.
I am not sure if I am doing something wrong on the `if - else` loop.

Thanks for pointing to the right direction for solving this problem.

Comment: It seems that you just forgot to call `minDistanceModelQuad3.setData()` when your `distanceBroadcasted` is empty

Comment: Thanks for stopping by and reading my question. Unfortunately I still don't get any change. I just updated the question adding the modification. Do you see something I don't see?

Comment: Who call the callback ? If the call is triggered when a measurement appears. are you sur the callback is called when nothing is measured ?

Comment: Ok I added the callback in the **listener.cpp**, is that useful?

Comment: Not really because your conditon in your callback is: `if (distanceBroadcasted.isEmpty())` but I can't see any piece of code where you modify this variable.

Comment: Ohh...I see what you mean. No all I have I posted above. I set on the **listener.h** `QString distanceBroadcasted = "";` as an empty string. And therefore when it is time to pass to `if (distanceBroadcasted.isEmpty())` it should give a different message because the string is hardcoded empty as an example to make sure I got the message.

Comment: But when there are messages it will switch to the other statement (which works correctly). The problem is that is not showing that string when there is nothing to show on the `QListView`.

Comment: Put a qDebug() in your callback, and just see if it is called

Comment: I have been playing with the message all yesterday afternoon and I also put your suggestion  `if(distanceBroadcasted.isEmpty()) {
    qDebug() << "Passing here??";` And it is not actually passing there. No trace on the terminal about that debugging statement. You are right.

Comment: Put the qDebug() before your `if` to see if the problem come from the condition or just because it is not called